# MongoDB 3.4 CopyTo deprecated

Tags: mongodb, deprecated

I would like to use db..copyTo("newCollection")
But I use a MongoDB 3.4 and copyTo is deprecated
The advantage is that the execution of copyTo is on the server side

So do you have a solution to do the same thing as copyTo and which is on the server side?

Thank you in advance and sorry in advance for my English which is not very good

Comment: [db.cloneCollection()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.cloneCollection/#db.cloneCollection). It's not "exactly" the same thing, but it is implemented without the serverside JavaScript that `copyTo()` is using. Note that "deprecated" does not mean "gone" ( yet ). But it definitely is going.

Comment: db.cloneCollection() copy a collection from one instance to another of the database. Here i would like to copy in the same instance. In fact i would like to make a $out of aggregation without the deletions.

Comment: You can still copy to the "same instance". Nothing stopping you doing that. Neither this or `$out` do a "merge" if that is what you are asking. All you have left for that option is "looping" and preferably using `.bulkWrite()`. The `copyTo()` method is deprecated because `eval()` is deprecated. Running JavaScript on the server like that is being removed.